# regexp to partly hide email?

Tags: php, regex, utf-8

It's rather simple what I'm trying to achieve, I want input such as

```
漢aelena@tratata.com
```

to be:

```
漢******@tratata.com
```

So I made this regexp to match between the first char and the '@'.

```
mb_regex_encoding ('UTF-8' );
mb_ereg_replace('(?<=^.{1}).*?(?=@)','*','漢aelena@tratata.com',1);
```

The problem though, it would only match it one time, and thus would only put in there one star, instead of six. Something like this, is what I would get:

```
漢*@tratata.com
```

Then I wanted to use mb_ereg_replace_callback, to return:

```
return $matches[1].str_repeat('*', strlen($matches[1]));
```

Then I read specs and it said mb_ereg_replace_callback is available in PHP 5.4.1 or later.

...Any ideas how could I achieve the same thing?

Comment: This is a professional Q&A site. We are not interested in your ranting and disappointment.

Comment: Have you thought about using the `preg_` family? You can use the `u` [modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) to support UTF-8.

Comment: Fully agree with @bažmegakapa. The first comment is childish and nonconstructive.

Comment: preg_ family? I have not heard of it... would you mind to elaborate a litle bit, or perhaps give it an answer :-) Thanks.

Comment: The preg_ funtions are the recommended means of doing REGEXP in PHP. The ereg_ functions are considered deprecated.

Comment: Yep, so I actually knew they were, I just thought I should use mb_ functions for unicode support, because it wasn't obvious from specs that I could just use an 'u' flag for a normal preg_replace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to use a callback function, a single regular expression can do it.

```
(?<=.).(?=.*@)
```

- `(?<=.)`, make sure there is at least one character before so it won't replace the first character.
- `.`, match any character.
- `(?=.*@)`, make sure there is a `@` somewhere after the character.

Example with function changed to `preg_replace` with unicode modifier (as suggested):

```
echo preg_replace('/(?<=.).(?=.*@)/u','*','漢aelena@tratata.com');
```

Outputs:

```
漢******@tratata.com
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Simple and compact. Thanks. I would replace though the ereg to preg and add the 'u' flag as suggested.

Comment: I changed the example as suggested.

Comment: You mean "character" not "letter"...

Comment: Yes, of course. I've never understood the difference before, but now I looked it up. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) function from the [PCRE family](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php). You can use the `u` [modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) to support UTF-8.

Please note there are [some smaller differences](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.posix.php) between the PCRE (`preg_`) and POSIX (`ereg_`) way, besides that the latter is deprecated.

Comment: do'h, I din't think of u modifier >.< gotta try it out then.. thanks

Comment: I know the preg_replace of course - that's what I would usually use

Comment: where do I put that flag though? :P i didn't see anything like that in the specs

Comment: From the [`preg_replace()` manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php): `$pattern = '/(\w+) (\d+), (\d+)/i';`, where `i` is a modifier.

Comment: Yeah, I found it now, but it wasn't obvious from the specs, so I guessed I should use mb_ functions for unicode - it's not my fault

Comment: @Anonymous With this attitude, you won't get far in this profession. Instead of blaming everything you can think of, focus on improving yourself. Blaming will make you an angry, frustrated guy - the other approach, on the other hand, can make you a programmer.

Comment: That's irrelevant. I am still learning and I didn't expect to recieve the replies in a manner that I would already knew everything, implying that I'm a foo if I didn't.

Comment: @Anonymous I don't think my attitude was anything like that. The attitude of others was driven by the way you asked your question - blaming PHP, instead of acting like a Learner. Please don't answer, I was trying to give advice, and we have too much comments already.

Comment: Alright, thanks for being the first one telling about the 'u' flag, learning about it is a great advancement for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$email = '漢aelena@tratata.com';

    $email = preg_replace_callback('#^(.){1}(.*?)@#u', function($matches)
            {
                return $matches[1] . str_repeat('*', mb_strlen($matches[2])) . '@';
            },
    $email);

echo $email; # 漢******@tratata.com
```

Answer (score 1):

A replacement callback is an option.

```
echo preg_replace_callback('/(?<=^.).+(?=@)/u', function($match) {
    return str_pad('', strlen($match[0]), '*');
}, "something@something.com");
//s*******@something.com
```

Note I use an anonymous function as the callback - this is PHP >= 5.3 only. If you're on < 5.3, use a named function or one created with `function_create()`.

Comment: those functions are not UTF-8 safe.

Answer (score -1):

Why use regexp at all when this can be done much faster?

```
if(($pos = mb_strpos($email,'@')) > 0) {
    for($i=1;$i<=$pos;$i++) {
        $email[$i] = '*';
    }
}
```

Comment: because I have headache thinking of mb_ functions emplementation

Comment: and your solution seems to be incomplete ... I have a hard time guessing what would I do with this peace of code :-) I would consider using it if you would elaborate on it's usage, so that would return a proper string

Comment: @Anonymous It's easy. In the beginning, `$email` contains the email. After the code runs, `$email` will contain the modified email. You could also create a function out of this.

Comment: @Anonymous You're not doing anyone a favour by "considering" their help. Judging from your (now deleted) rant on PHP in the original post I assumed you know it well enough to at least understand a simple loop code. I was wrong.

Comment: It 'doesn't work: returns �******a@tratata.com

Comment: I would have understood if it had worked, but from my first glace it didn't look like it would work at all. I gave it a try and I wasn't mistaken

Comment: $email[$i] obviously won't work with multibytes...

Comment: @lafor $string[1] is the first byte... your method could be completed with mb_ functions http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php