# Partially hide email addresses with PHP regular expression?

Tags: php, regex, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [regexp to partly hide email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708565/regexp-to-partly-hide-email)

I'm currently writing a script that hides an email address (so test@domain.com becomes t~~~@~~~~~~.com).

Whilst following the instructions on this question - [regexp to partly hide email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708565/regexp-to-partly-hide-email) - I have managed to get it to display t~~~@domain.com, but am having trouble removing the "domain".

Here is what I have so far (assume $row->email is "test@domain.com"):-

```
$string = preg_replace("(?<=.).(?=.*@)","~", $row->email);
$string = preg_replace("(?<=@).[a-zA-Z0-9]*","~", $string);
```

However, all it returns is t~~~@~omain.com

I'm baffled as to how to get the rest of the domain bit. Ideas?

IDEALLY if anybody can provide a solution so it becomes t~~~@d~~~~~~.com, that'd be super.

Cheers

Comment: may as well just remove the address altogether.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is ..

- matching (and skipping) `"@"` and then;
- matching `.` (any character: i.e. the `"d"` in `"domain"`) and then;
- matching **0 (zero)** of the following character class, which is the *minimum it needed* to match the supplied regular expression.

That is, the *first and only the first* character after the `@` was matched and replaced with `~`.

The following

```
(?<=@.)[a-zA-Z0-9-]*(?=(?:[.]|$))
```

forces the character class to match to the first `"."` (period, as in `".com"`) or end-of-input.

Note that the `.` is moved *inside* of the `(?<=@.)`-look-behind clause which causes it to skip the first letter after the `"@"`. I have also added a hyphen (`"-"`) to the character class as they are valid (and not terribly uncommon) in domain names.

In addition, not all email addresses are in the trivial `"a@b.c"` form and [Internationalized Domain Names (or IDN)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name) *can* be represented locally in a non-[punycode](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3492) form when not transmitted (e.g. not used in a restricting context), but that is another topic. (It may be more appropriate to replace `[a-zA-Z0-9-]*` with `[^.]*` due to IDN without further specification.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this as well, if nothing, it is at least quite easy to read and modify:

```
$email = $row->email;
$atPos = strpos( $email, "@" );
preg_match('/(\..*?)$/', $email, $topDomain, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
$emailLength = strlen($email);

$hiddenEmail = $email[0] . 
               str_repeat('~', $atPos-1) . 
               "@" . 
               $email[$atPos + 1] . 
               str_repeat('~', $topDomain[1][1]-$atPos-2) . 
               $topDomain[1][0];
```